# Failed to write core dump after removing class

Tags: android, minidump

All off a sudden I started to get a JavaThread crash.
I created a class in my project and then I deleted it, the class was SoundPlayer.
Think thats the problem because at the end of the log it tries "java command com.qwerty.testapp.SoundPlayer".
I've tried to do clean project, remove debug.keystore and now im all out of ideas. 
Any suggestions on how to fix this?

BR

```
 #
    # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
    #
    #  Internal Error (javaClasses.cpp:136), pid=3420, tid=4012
    #  fatal error: Invalid layout of preloaded class
    #
    # JRE version:  (7.0_51-b13) (build )
    # Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
    # Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
    #
    # If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
    #   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
    #

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x0000000002de0800):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=4012, stack(0x0000000002ce0000,0x0000000002de0000)]

Stack: [0x0000000002ce0000,0x0000000002de0000]

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )

Other Threads:

=>0x0000000002de0800 (exited) JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_vm, id=4012, stack(0x0000000002ce0000,0x0000000002de0000)]

VM state:not at safepoint (not fully initialized)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (0 events):
No events

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.010 loading class 0x0000000002e24600 done
Event: 0.011 loading class 0x0000000002e24020 done
Event: 0.011 loading class 0x0000000002e24000
Event: 0.011 loading class 0x0000000002e2c100
Event: 0.011 loading class 0x0000000002e2c100 done
Event: 0.011 loading class 0x0000000002e2c130
Event: 0.011 loading class 0x0000000002e2c130 done
Event: 0.011 loading class 0x0000000002e2c160
Event: 0.011 loading class 0x0000000002e2c160 done
Event: 0.011 loading class 0x0000000002e24000 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff7b4e60000 - 0x00007ff7b4e93000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
0x00007ffd77f60000 - 0x00007ffd78109000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ffd76d30000 - 0x00007ffd76e69000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ffd753b0000 - 0x00007ffd754bf000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ffd73d70000 - 0x00007ffd73dfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\apphelp.dll
0x00007ffd6f800000 - 0x00007ffd6f84f000     C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\AppPatch64\AcGenral.DLL
0x00007ffd772d0000 - 0x00007ffd77377000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ffd75190000 - 0x00007ffd751bb000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SspiCli.dll
0x00007ffd773e0000 - 0x00007ffd77431000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x00007ffd77de0000 - 0x00007ffd77f51000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x00007ffd77c60000 - 0x00007ffd77dd6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x00007ffd758b0000 - 0x00007ffd76cbf000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ffd74970000 - 0x00007ffd7498f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x00007ffd75800000 - 0x00007ffd758a5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ffd6d130000 - 0x00007ffd6d14b000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x00007ffd76e70000 - 0x00007ffd76fa6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ffd77380000 - 0x00007ffd773d7000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x00007ffd77640000 - 0x00007ffd77817000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\combase.dll
0x00007ffd76fb0000 - 0x00007ffd770f5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ffd752e0000 - 0x00007ffd752f4000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\profapi.dll
0x00007ffd73510000 - 0x00007ffd735b1000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SHCORE.dll
0x00007ffd77290000 - 0x00007ffd772c4000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x00007ffd77b10000 - 0x00007ffd77c48000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x00007ffd6cd00000 - 0x00007ffd6cd34000     C:\Windows\system32\nvinitx.dll
0x000000000f000000 - 0x000000000f006000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\_etoured.dll
0x00007ffd6cc70000 - 0x00007ffd6cc9d000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvd3d9wrapx.dll
0x00007ffd77880000 - 0x00007ffd77a56000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SETUPAPI.dll
0x00007ffd756f0000 - 0x00007ffd7573a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CFGMGR32.dll
0x00007ffd6cc10000 - 0x00007ffd6cc32000     C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CoProcManager\nvdxgiwrapx.dll
0x00007ffd72f70000 - 0x00007ffd731ca000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.9600.16384_none_62475f7becb72503\COMCTL32.dll
0x0000000069d20000 - 0x0000000069df2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000069550000 - 0x0000000069d19000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ffd62500000 - 0x00007ffd62509000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ffd6dc20000 - 0x00007ffd6dc3f000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ffd77c50000 - 0x00007ffd77c57000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ffd77440000 - 0x00007ffd77498000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ffd6dbf0000 - 0x00007ffd6dc1a000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ffd77280000 - 0x00007ffd77289000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\NSI.dll
0x00007ffd74190000 - 0x00007ffd741b6000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\DEVOBJ.dll
0x000000006aba0000 - 0x000000006abaf000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000069520000 - 0x0000000069548000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x000000006ab80000 - 0x000000006ab95000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252 -Xbootclasspath:C:\Android\sdk\platforms\android-19\android.jar 
java_command: com.qwerty.testapp.SoundPlayer
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Android\sdk\platform-tools
USERNAME=qwerty
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 69 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8 , 64 bit Build 9200 

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 69 stepping 1, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 8270188k(5215628k free), swap 9580908k(5853552k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.51-b03) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_51-b13), built on Dec 18 2013 18:40:56 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Wed Feb 19 21:16:26 2014
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: This is an error from the JVM on your development machine, not from the device.  The Android build system will utilize the JVM, so this could be a toolchain error.  But what it really looks like to me is that you are using the wrong launch button, and as a result trying to build your Android project as normal Java code and then execute it on the development machine, rather than build an Android .apk and deploy it to an emulator or device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it thanks to @Chris Stratton.
Went under "run as configuration" and there the deleted class was selected under "java application".
Deleted the settings for that class and voilá, now the error went away.